# I dont understand this error in MATLAB about rows and columns

Tags: matlab

[image: this is figure 1 that is being used]    Pos=get(2,'Position');
set(2,'Position',Pos+[0  -200   0   200])

```
%Script_dtmf_filter.m
close all
clear
clc

phone_num=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0];
[x,Fs] = dtmf(phone_num);
N=2400;
n=[1:2*N-1];

%filterDesigner -->export filter object-->save to file-->load
load filter_697.mat
load filter_770.mat


y697=filter(filter_697,x);
y770=filter(filter_770,x);

load filter_LP.mat

figure(1)
Pos=get(1,'Position');
set(1,'Position',Pos+[0  -200   0   200])

subplot(7,1,1),plot(y697)   
subplot(7,1,2),plot(y770)   

  
y697out=filter(filter_LP,y697.^2);   y(1,:)=double(y697out>.3);
y770out=filter(filter_LP,y770.^2);   y(2,:)=double(y770out>.3);

figure(2)
Pos=get(2,'Position');
set(2,'Position',Pos+[0  -200   0   200])

for p=1:7
    subplot(7,1,p), plot(y(p,:),'LineWidth',2)
end

for q=1:7
   %can use group delay or figure 1 as an offset guide setting XXX 
   d(q,:)=downsample(y(q,:),2500,1882);
end

disp(num2str(d))
numarray=[1 2 3;4 5 6; 7 8 9; -1 0 -2];
num=zeros(1,length(x)/2400);
for r=1:10
index=find(d(:,r)==1);
row= index(1); col=index(2)-4;
num(1,r)=numarray(row,col);
end
disp(' ')
disp(['  Transmitted Data =  ',num2str(num)])
```

everything before the comment line %can use group delay, executes properly. The goal of that line is to Determine down sampling offset to determine presence of filter output power. my question is how do I determine the group value or the value for xxx based on downsampling or using figure 1. The error is at the bottom

Index exceeds the number of array elements (1).

```
Error in Script_dtmf_filter_XXX (line 67)
row= index(1); col=index(2)-4;
```

Comment: Can you post all the code that replicates the error? I can't seem to replicate it with the existing code given.

Comment: I can't really put whole code because it using filterDesigner and most of the code is in a separte m file, so it would be hard to run it

Comment: My question I think is more like how do I determine the value from x using group delay or figure 1

Comment: figure 1 was added

Comment: What is the length/size of `index`? It's possible that `index` does not have a 2nd index that can be accessed.

Comment: length should be 9 based off of                                                                    phone_num=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0];
[x,Fs] = dtmf(phone_num);
N=2400;
n=[1:2*N-1];

Comment: Is that what the workspace shows?

Comment: The error says that `index` has one value, so `index(2)` is illegal. What are you trying to do in that line of code?

Comment: it takes the values the filter created and supposed to downsample it based on figure 1 or group sampling

Comment: that's part of the code from the workspace the pervious lines executed the code to get figure 1

Comment: whole code has been added except the lines to load the filters

Comment: `find(d(:,r)==1)` this, whatever it does,  only finds 1 instance where the condition is applied, and therefore `index` is only 1 value.

Comment: so what should it be then?